# How does one create Website UI guidelines?

Tags: website-design, guidelines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How did you create design guidelines for your organization?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/how-did-you-create-design-guidelines-for-your-organization)

What points do you need to consider while writing the UI guidelines for a website. How much in depth should you go as regards each point. Could anyone refer me a sample of these guidelines.

Comment: Do you mean UI guidelines as per a style guide for an organizational site or are you referring to something guiding the general design of sites?  Is this to be placed within an existing framework or ... ?

More information would be helpful to provide an answer.

Comment: UI guidelines as per a style guide for an organizational site

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related, but a related question was asked and answered last week: [How did you create design guidelines for your organization?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/how-did-you-create-design-guidelines-for-your-organization)